# How to format string as currency given the currency code/symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to format a string as a currency given the currency code and not the locale. That is, given `USD` and not `en_US`.

I have seen examples on how to format it using `value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))`
but something like this does not work
`value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("USD"))`

Is there any way to format the string as such?

Comment: You’ll have to map the currency to a culture

Comment: i suspect you are goinjg to need a dictionary mapping currenies to locale names ie USD=>en-US, GBP=>en-UK....

Comment: I think your question looks like `Globalization and localization in asp.net core`, Maybe you can refer to this [ssue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/433479/setting-currency-independent-of-culture.html).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a map of all Cultures with their corresponding `ISOCurrencySymbol` value.

```
ILookup<string, CultureInfo> cultureByCurrency = 
    CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
    .Where(x => { try { _ = new RegionInfo(x.LCID); return true; } catch { return false; }})
    .ToLookup(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID).ISOCurrencySymbol);
```

```
cultureByCurrency["USD"].First().Name; // "en-US"
cultureByCurrency["CNY"].First().Name; // "bo-CN"

foreach (var culture in cultureByCurrency["EUR"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(culture.Name);
}
// gives br-FR ca-ES de-AT de-DE de-LU dsb-DE el-GR en-IE es-ES et-EE eu-ES fi-FI fr-BE fr-FR fr-LU
// fr-MC fr-RE fy-NL ga-IE gl-ES gsw-FR hsb-DE it-IT lb-LU lt-LT lv-LV mt-MT nl-BE
// nl-NL pt-PT se-FI sk-SK sl-SI smn-FI sr-Cyrl-ME sr-Latn-ME sv-FI
```

The `Where` is... well, it's a bit jank. Apparently there are some cultures from `SpecificCultures` that don't have an `ISOCurrencySymbol`, so that filters out those that can't be looked up.

More info about the lookup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533112/1043380), and the ISOCurrentySymbol property [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2763519/1043380)

Comment: Side note: while this answers the question OP has, it is a wrong suggestion if one looking for correct results. Unfortunately there is no way to code "use this culture's currency formatting but a different currency symbol". As result everyone grabs a somewhat random culture that happen to use the given currency and formats the value with that... ending up with "2.5 apples will cost you 2,50$" :(